# Context-free Grammar Exercise

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Could someone explain me how to form a context-free grammar with all rules R by this example language, please? 
\begin{equation}
L:=\left\{w c v c \overleftarrow{w} | w, v \in\{a, b\}^{+}\right\}
\end{equation}
The arrow over w means, that the word w is written backwards.

I already know that \begin{equation}
\Sigma=\{a, b, c\}
\end{equation}
and V (non terminal symbols) maybe have to be \begin{equation}
V=\{S, A, B, C\}
\end{equation}

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this using this construct:

$$S \rightarrow ASA|BSB|ATA|BTB $$
$$T \rightarrow CAZC|CBZC$$
$$Z \rightarrow AZ|BZ|\epsilon$$
$$A \rightarrow a , B \rightarrow b, C \rightarrow c$$

First rule provides the $w$ and $w^R$ in the language, second rule makes sure $v \ge 1$ and has 1 c in both sides and third is just constructing the $v$ further. My assumption was your arrow on top of last $w$ was just meant it is reversed.

Comment: Could you explain what T and Z mean in your rules?
Do you mean the word backwards with \begin{equation}
w^{R} \text { ?}
\end{equation}

Comment: I just use those arbitrary non-terminals to impose extra rules. Using "S" to impose the $w$ and $w^R$ rule then using T to make sure we got $|v| \ge 1$ and Z to create any $ |v| > 1$. As I said they are arbitrary non-terminals , you can use this kind of rules as long as they abide by the rules of your language.

Comment: So you mean, v can not be greater than 1, because it can not be ϵ because of the +. Right?

Comment: v has to be greater than 1, because of $v \in \{a,b\}^+$. I think I made a mistake, lemme fix it, because I forgot $w \in \{a,b\}^+$ as well

Comment: No problem. Yes, you can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: It should be correct now, by $w^R$ I meant if w=ab then $w^R$= ba.